# Why does tortoise svn show the modified directory icon overlay when there are no modified files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Why does tortoise svn show the modified directory icon overlay when there are no modified files in the directory ?

And *how* can I know the reason it is doing that, using tortoise itself ?

The directory in question has the property svn:mergeinfo (only this sub-directory, not the others), and I can't get tortoise to remove the modified icon from the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Either it has not refreshed the status of directory

OR

It could be that directory svn-properties have been modified.

Properties can get modified by third party applications or when you do merges.